# ATLGetDacl accessing 64bit reg keys from a 32bit process

Tags: c++, windows, registry, atl

I am trying to get DACL information of a 64bit registry key from a 32bit process.

```
AtlGetDacl("Machine\Software\Somekey", SE_REGISTRY_KEY, &dacl)
```

This redirects to "Machine\Software\Wow6432Node\Somekey" , since I am running a 32bit process.

What I need is something like the samDesired flag which is available in Windows Registry functions (like RegOpenKeyEx), do you know if ATL has such a thing and how I can pass that to ATLGetDacl and ATLSetDacl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another overload of `AtlGetDacl` can take a registry key as an argument.

```
inline bool AtlGetDacl(
    _In_ HANDLE hObject,
    _In_ SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
    _Inout_ CDacl *pDacl) throw(...)
```

You can use it for a key you already know how to open with `RegOpenKeyEx`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, that's what I understood. And he knows how to do it with RegOpenKeyEx, as he says, so that's the way to do: open key separately, then pass to another AtlGetDacl overload, which this way will be able to bypass the redirection

Comment: ah, I was wondering if that would work. great, I'll give that a try, thanks a lot.